# Getting at InfoPath/form library data using LINQ to SharePoint

Tags: infopath, linq, visual-web-part, spmetal

I'm teaching myself some basic SharePoint stuff, coming from three-tier ASP.NET, and before that, Java background.  I've been trying to figure out how to do things "the SharePoint" way, rather than just diving into code, but I find that coding is sometimes the only way to get stuff done in SharePoint.  Anyway, here's my question:

I've got an InfoPath form with some repeating fields that I've published to a SharePoint server, and I'm writing a Visual Web Part that I'd like to use to display data from the items in the form library.  I figured out how to get InfoPath fields to act like SharePoint columns, and I used spmetal to generate the objects I need to access the data by LINQ, but I can't figure out how to get at the info path fields that aren't set up as SharePoint columns.  How can I get at that data?